How to pass a variable in a string block?
In the following example code, I am trying to use graphql query and I have to pass the value of a string that I get from the command-line argument in the query:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    input := os.Args[1]
    jsonData := map[string]string{
        "query": `
           mutation manager($input: managerinput!) {
              manager(input: $input) {
                 name {
                  
                  }
               error {
                 ...SystemError
                }
               }
            }

        `,
    }
    jsonValue, _ := json.Marshal(jsonData)
    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://<GRAPHQL_API_HERE>", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))
    client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    defer response.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    }
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}

How do I pass the value of input in the query block? the $input is not working but I am new and I am unable to find a way to pass the value of a variable inside a multi-line string block "query", that starts and ends with `.

Use text/template (Go playground):
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
)

type Param struct {
    Input string
}

func main() {
    param := Param{Input: "some string"}

    tmpl, err := template.New("query").Parse(`
           mutation manager({{js .Input}}: managerinput!) {
              manager(input: {{js .Input}}) {
                 name {
                  
                  }
               error {
                 ...SystemError
                }
               }
            }
        `)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var s strings.Builder
    err = tmpl.Execute(&s, param)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    query := s.String()

    fmt.Println(query)

    jsonData := map[string]string{
        "query": query,
    }

    jsonValue, err := json.MarshalIndent(jsonData, "*", " ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(jsonValue))
}

Refer to the documentation for details:

Templates are executed by applying them to a data structure. Annotations in the template refer to elements of the data structure (typically a field of a struct or a key in a map) to control execution and derive values to be displayed.

So, I'm using .Input here as the (exported) field of my Param structure and js as a function to escape the argument.

Using this gives me the error: executing query at : can't evaluate field input in type string but using it without the js works

@winterlyrock js works in the Go Playground, though...

You can use fmt.Sprintf similar to how you're already using fmt.printf (I believe you may still define a multi-line string starting/ending it with `).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
